# wordpress htaccess issue with custom rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is driving me crazy. Its definitely not a cache issue and I've tested the rules at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, all work ok. But for some reason I cant get ANY rewriterules to work. I've just added a simple one for testing but if anyone could suggest its maybe wordpress or it is something glaringly obvious in my htaccess?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#rewrites
RewriteRule ^test.html$ http://www.google.co.uk/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


#redirects

Redirect 301 /success-stories.html /success-stories/
Redirect 301 /introductions-agency-news/ /dating-agency-news/
Redirect 301 /how-do-we-do-it.html /our-service/
Redirect 301 /1.html /

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

In host admin There's a config directive called AllowOverride where you specify which config directives can be overridden by .htaccess. I originally had it set to allowing specific features which included ReWrite. However, I just set it to "All" and obviously, that seems to have done it.